# Rails 3 and rmagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rmagick

I have problem with rmagick in Rails 3.

Everything seems to be installed, but I get the following error:

> Failed to manipulate with rmagick, maybe it is not an image? Original
>   Error: unable to open image
>   `kar/public/uploads/tmp/20110825-1348-30304-9150/thumb_1314198312_by_jannnu11_500.jpg':
>   @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2588

File exists. Have good chmod.

This code works on another server.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In some cases the installation of ImageMagick may have missed some of the file formats required for the image manipulation you are trying to do on that machine.

Try to run `identify -list format` and see what you are missing from there. 
If it turns out that you are just missing the file format, try to uninstall/reinstall and you should be good to go.